# Find Nodes inside Path

Tags: path, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want the player to draw on the screen, creating a path. If he closes the encircling path, I want to do stuff to the nodes inside the path.

How do I know which nodes are inside the path?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you store the coordinates of all your nodes or have a reference to them in a variable.

You can make use of `CGRectContainsPoint` to check for nodes inside the closed path by making use of the node's coordinate.

To get the rect from a CGPath,from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathGetBoundingBox)

```
func CGPathGetBoundingBox(_ path: CGPath!) -> CGRect
```

Comment: You can convert it to a rectangle, there are functions made for it

Comment: What if I draw a circular path, then the nodes in the corners of the bounding box would be included...